# Why using pretrained ResNet50 results in contradictory losses in training and validation set?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, computer-vision, resnet

I'm using ResNet50 pretrained model as building block for a Unet:

```
def ResNet50(include_top=True, weights='imagenet',
         input_tensor=None, input_shape=None,
         pooling=None,
         classes=1000):
if weights not in {'imagenet', None}:
    raise ValueError('The `weights` argument should be either '
                     '`None` (random initialization) or `imagenet` '
                     '(pre-training on ImageNet).')

if weights == 'imagenet' and include_top and classes != 1000:
    raise ValueError('If using `weights` as imagenet with `include_top`'
                     ' as true, `classes` should be 1000')

if input_tensor is None:
    img_input = Input(shape=input_shape)
else:
    if not K.is_keras_tensor(input_tensor):
        img_input = Input(tensor=input_tensor, shape=input_shape)
    else:
        img_input = input_tensor
if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_last':
    bn_axis = 3
else:
    bn_axis = 1

x = Conv2D(64, (7, 7), strides=(2, 2), padding='same', name='conv1')(img_input)
x = BatchNormalization(axis=bn_axis, name='bn_conv1')(x)
x = Activation('relu')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D((3, 3), strides=(2, 2), padding="same")(x)

x = conv_block(x, 3, [64, 64, 256], stage=2, block='a', strides=(1, 1))
x = identity_block(x, 3, [64, 64, 256], stage=2, block='b')
x = identity_block(x, 3, [64, 64, 256], stage=2, block='c')

x = conv_block(x, 3, [128, 128, 512], stage=3, block='a')
x = identity_block(x, 3, [128, 128, 512], stage=3, block='b')
x = identity_block(x, 3, [128, 128, 512], stage=3, block='c')
x = identity_block(x, 3, [128, 128, 512], stage=3, block='d')

x = conv_block(x, 3, [256, 256, 1024], stage=4, block='a')
x = identity_block(x, 3, [256, 256, 1024], stage=4, block='b')
x = identity_block(x, 3, [256, 256, 1024], stage=4, block='c')
x = identity_block(x, 3, [256, 256, 1024], stage=4, block='d')
x = identity_block(x, 3, [256, 256, 1024], stage=4, block='e')
x = identity_block(x, 3, [256, 256, 1024], stage=4, block='f')

x = conv_block(x, 3, [512, 512, 2048], stage=5, block='a')
x = identity_block(x, 3, [512, 512, 2048], stage=5, block='b')
x = identity_block(x, 3, [512, 512, 2048], stage=5, block='c')

# Ensure that the model takes into account
# any potential predecessors of `input_tensor`.
if input_tensor is not None:
    inputs = get_source_inputs(input_tensor)
else:
    inputs = img_input
# Create model.
model = Model(inputs, x, name='resnet50')

# load weights
if weights == 'imagenet':
    if include_top:
        weights_path = get_file('resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels.h5',
                                WEIGHTS_PATH,
                                cache_subdir='models',
                                md5_hash='a7b3fe01876f51b976af0dea6bc144eb')
    else:
        weights_path = get_file('resnet50_weights_tf_dim_ordering_tf_kernels_notop.h5',
                                WEIGHTS_PATH_NO_TOP,
                                cache_subdir='models',
                                md5_hash='a268eb855778b3df3c7506639542a6af')
    model.load_weights(weights_path,by_name=True)
return model
```

Creating the Unet:

```
def conv_block_simple(prevlayer, filters, prefix, strides=(1, 1)):
conv = Conv2D(filters, (3, 3), padding="same", kernel_initializer="he_normal", strides=strides, name=prefix + "_conv")(prevlayer)
conv = BatchNormalization(name=prefix + "_bn")(conv)
conv = Activation('relu', name=prefix + "_activation")(conv)
return conv 

def conv_block_simple_no_bn(prevlayer, filters, prefix, strides=(1, 1)):
conv = Conv2D(filters, (3, 3), padding="same", kernel_initializer="he_normal", strides=strides, name=prefix + "_conv")(prevlayer)
conv = Activation('relu', name=prefix + "_activation")(conv)
return conv

K.clear_session()

def get_unet_resnet(input_shape):
    resnet_base = ResNet50(input_shape=input_shape, include_top=False)

    for l in resnet_base.layers:
        l.trainable = False 


    conv1 = resnet_base.get_layer("activation_1").output
    conv2 = resnet_base.get_layer("activation_10").output
    conv3 = resnet_base.get_layer("activation_22").output
    conv4 = resnet_base.get_layer("activation_40").output
    conv5 = resnet_base.get_layer("activation_49").output

    up6 = concatenate([UpSampling2D()(conv5), conv4], axis=-1)
    conv6 = conv_block_simple(up6, 256, "conv6_1")
    conv6 = conv_block_simple(conv6, 256, "conv6_2")

    up7 = concatenate([UpSampling2D()(conv6), conv3], axis=-1)
    conv7 = conv_block_simple(up7, 192, "conv7_1")
    conv7 = conv_block_simple(conv7, 192, "conv7_2")

    up8 = concatenate([UpSampling2D()(conv7), conv2], axis=-1)
    conv8 = conv_block_simple(up8, 128, "conv8_1")
    conv8 = conv_block_simple(conv8, 128, "conv8_2")

    up9 = concatenate([UpSampling2D()(conv8), conv1], axis=-1)
    conv9 = conv_block_simple(up9, 64, "conv9_1")
    conv9 = conv_block_simple(conv9, 64, "conv9_2")

    up10 = UpSampling2D()(conv9)
    conv10 = conv_block_simple(up10, 32, "conv10_1")
    conv10 = conv_block_simple(conv10, 32, "conv10_2")
    conv10 = SpatialDropout2D(0.2)(conv10)
    x = Conv2D(1, (1, 1), activation="sigmoid", name="prediction")(conv10)

    model = Model(resnet_base.input, x)

    model.summary()

    return model
```

I freezed the pretrained ResNet50 layers as proposed in several papers:

```
for l in resnet_base.layers:
    l.trainable = False
```

Without the freezing the network works fine, but tends to hugely overfit, which I decreased with higher `SpatialDropout2D()` value. 
When I freeze it however the train losses decrease but the validation losses circulate about some weird high value but actually stagnate.
I can't figure out, why the frozen network do work on training set, meanwhile it doesn't on validation set. I see no logical reason for it (on my current knowledge level).

I tried playing with learning rate, but no success.

What could be the problem?
Any help would be highly appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have a similar problem with the validation accuracy on ResNet50 - it is constantly low, even though the training accuracy is very good. Please share

Answer (score 1):

There is certaing problem (Keras creators are keen it is design) with BN layers in Keras. The problem is that during the training, BN layers are actually learning parameters of your new dataset, while during validation phase the parametrs of dataset ResNet was trained with are used (e.g. imagenet or cifar).
This results into good training accuracy, but validation accuracy will be just nonexistant.

You can find more [here](http://blog.datumbox.com/the-batch-normalization-layer-of-keras-is-broken/)

Comment: Thank you for your info and link. Though I couldn't still check if it is the case on my side, but I found it useful, so I gave an up for it. Later if I will make a test and it works I will accept the answer of course.